# How to list top 10 process/services in terminal

Tags: terminal, script, monitoring

I'm trying to run a command every 5 min to check the top 10 services/process that are using more CPU.

I would like to run the script and save the result in a file and after 5 min add the new result in the same document.

I would like to be able to see: CPU, Memory, Disk, Network if it's possible.

I have tried `top -R -u -s 10` but this doesn't contain all the information I need.

Comment: Well, what information is missing?

Comment: I would like only to see the top 10, also save the information in a file every time I run the command the new report needs to be added to the bottom of the file.